# Only one jquery ajax post doesnt work in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I have a problem with ajax post in Firefox.

My code:

```
var addStats = function(id, type) {
   $.ajax({
      url: '/api.php',
      type: "POST",
      data: {
          id: id,
          type: type
      }
  }).done(function(res){
      console.log('[STATS] Success.');
  }).fail(function() {
      console.log('[STATS] Error.');
  });
};
```

This code works correctly in Chrome, Opera, IE and Edge but no in Firefox.

I will add that the website also supports sending of forms and it works correctly...
Other code that works in firefox:

```
$.ajax({
   url: form.attr("action"),
   type: "POST",
   data: form.serialize()
}).done(function(res){
    //
}).fail(function() {
   // 
});
```

Comment: do you get any warning or errors in the console?

Comment: No. I have only console.log from fail().